# Plot with ticks at different levels

Tags: r, plot, label

I would like to know if it is possible to put the ticks labels at two different levels to avoid overlapping between labels.
For example here:

```
a=c[1:10]
b=c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October")
barplot(a,space=0,axes=F)
ticks=a
axis(side=1, at =ticks, labels=b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the following:

```
a=1:10
b=c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October")
barplot(a,space=0,axes=F)
ticks=a

# indices of even ticks
idx <- seq(2, length(ticks), 2) 

# b2 only contains the odd labels.
b2 <- b
# Empty space so a small line gets drawn at omitted labels
b2[idx] <- ""

# draw odd labels
axis(side=1, at =ticks, labels=b2, line = 0)
# same command for even ticks, lwd = 0 suppresses drawing the x-axis twice
axis(side=1, at =ticks[idx], labels=b[idx], line = 1, lwd = 0)
```

This basically circumvents overlapping by first drawing the labels at odd positions and then drawing the labels at even positions but slightly lower due to `line = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do two `axis` calls, one for odd months and one for even ones and put them on different `line`. The first `axis` call is simply to draw the ticks, without labels.

```
a=1:10
a_even <- a[a %% 2==0]
a_odd <- a[a %% 2==1]
b=c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October")
barplot(a,space=0,axes=F)
ticks=a
axis(side=1, at =ticks, labels=FALSE,line = 1)
axis(side=1, at =ticks[a_odd], labels=b[a_odd],line = 1,tick = FALSE)
axis(side=1, at =ticks[a_even], labels=b[a_even],line = 2,tick = FALSE)
```

[image]